# How to call a method in python that is in a different class, where the class is in a different file?

Tags: python, algorithm, file, class, methods

I have a file named `main.py` which contains a class called `mainWindow`. I have a second file named `popupWindow.py`, which contains a class named `popupWindow`. `mainWindow` class contains 2 methods. One called `clearListBox` which clears the list box in the main window, and one called `addScouts(I)` which is a recursive function for writing the scouts stored in a file to the list box. I would like to be able to call the `clearListBox` and `addScouts(I)` from my class `popupWindow`. How do i achieve this?

upon trying `from main import mainWindow` then calling `mainWindow.addScouts(1)` i received the error that `addScouts` requires arg `self`

In my `main.py` file:

```
class mainWindow:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        self._scouts = []
        addBtn = Button(master,text="Create Scout",command=self._createScout)
        addBtn.pack()
        remBtn = Button(master,text="Remove Scout",command=self._removeScout)
        remBtn.pack()
        fndBtn = Button(master,text="Find Scout",command=self._findScout)
        fndBtn.pack()
        exitBtn = Button(master,text="Exit",command=self._exit)
        exitBtn.pack()
        scoutList = Listbox(master)
        scoutList.pack()
        self.scoutList = scoutList
        self.addScouts(1)
        w = 1000 #The value of the width
        h = 750 #The value of the height of the window

        # get screen width and height
        ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()#This value is the width of the screen
        hs = root.winfo_screenheight()#This is the height of the screen

        # calculate position x, y
        x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
        y = (hs/2) - (h/2)

        #This is responsible for setting the dimensions of the screen and where it is
        #placed
        root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
        self._createLeaderboard()

    def addScouts(self,I):
        i = I
        with open(fileName,"r") as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            for line in lines:
                if str(line.split(",")[3])[:-1] == str(i):
                    self.scoutList.insert(END,line[:-1])
                    i += 1
                    return self.addScouts(i)
        return

    def clearListBox(self):
        self.scoutList.delete(0,END)
        return
```

In `popupWindow.py`:

```
from main import mainWindow
```

In `popupWindow` class:

```
mainWindow.clearListBox()
mainWindow.addScouts(1)
```

My Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KRIS\Documents\Python Projects\Scouts\popupWindow.py", line     4, in <module>
    from main import mainWindow
  File "C:\Users\KRIS\Documents\Python Projects\Scouts\main.py", line 4, in     <module>
    from popupWindow import *
  File "C:\Users\KRIS\Documents\Python Projects\Scouts\popupWindow.py", line 4, in <module>
    from main import mainWindow
ImportError: cannot import name 'mainWindow'
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You could do this by importing the classes you need using the [`import`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) pattern. Try to import your class containing the desired method by using the [`import-from`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules) as shown for submodules statement. However, you should think about your file- resp. directory-structure regarding main- and helper-files, because it seems you want to import main methods into a helper file.

Comment: `import` is a keyword of the language, not a "pattern"

Comment: Post some code @AdminHydra

Comment: Your code sample is incomplete.

Comment: Are you sure that `addScouts(self,I)` is a method of your `mainWindow` class?

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور Yes positive

Comment: I doubt that, Can you post more code about the classes?...

Comment: Or may be you can give us a link to your complete code, try to upload it here:
https://bpaste.net/

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور i added the `mainWindow` class decleration, with method declerations

Comment: First thing: indentation error!!!..

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور its not like that in my code, i assure you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81124/discussion-between-khalil-ammour---and-admin-hydra).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been asked times and times again - and is nothing Python-specific. To call a method on *an instance* of another class, you need to have a reference to this instance. The very obvious solution is to pass this reference, either at call time:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, var_a):
        self.var_a = var_a

    def method(self, another_object):
        return another_object.another_method(self.var_a)


class B(object):
    def __init__(self, var_b):
        self.var_b = var_b

    def another_method(self, var):
        return self.var_b + var


a = A(42)
b = B(1138)
print a.method(b)
```

or at instanciation time:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, var_a, another_object):
        self.var_a = var_a
        self.another_object = another_object

    def method(self):
        return self.another_object.another_method(self.var_a)


class B(object):
    def __init__(self, var_b):
        self.var_b = var_b

    def another_method(self, var):
        return self.var_b + var

b = b(1138)
a = A(b)
print a.method()
```

Note that in both cases, `B` doesn't need to know about class `A` - it just gets an instance as param and that's it. So if `A` and `B` live in different modules, the module containing `B` doesn't have to import the one containing `A`:

```
# module b.py
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, var_b):
        self.var_b = var_b

    def another_method(self, var):
        return self.var_b + var

# module a.py

from b import B

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, var_a, another_object):
        self.var_a = var_a
        self.another_object = another_object

    def method(self):
        return self.another_object.another_method(self.var_a)

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    b = b(1138)
    a = A(b)
    print a.method()
```

which avoids the circular import error you obviously have given your traceback.

Comment: This does not help me, as my classes are stored in different files, which seems to be causing the issues

Comment: @AdminHydra importing a module from another one shouldn't be much a problem from someone who claims to understand Python, should it ? I mean, it's part of the tutorial... https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Comment: And I'm sorry to have to say that you also need to understand the above - specially the difference between a class and an instance.

Comment: I have attempted this, as shown in my question, and got an error, as shown in my question

Comment: I do also understand the difference between a class and an instance, The instance of mainWindow class is called mainWin, and is created at the bottom of main.py in the if statement `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Comment: Please read the tutorial - the part about the module search path (which I linked to) and the part about what makes a python package (in the same section of the tutorial).

Comment: Just for the fun of it: could it be that `main.py` has an `import popupWindow` at the top level ? If yes look no further - you do "understand Python" but not enough to understand what a circular import is obviously. And if you really understood my answer you'd know you don't even need to import `main` from `popupWindow` : assuming your `popupWindow.popupWindow|`instance is created by `mainWindow`, you just have ot pass the `mainWindow` instance to `popupWindow`.

Comment: aha yes indeed there is a `import popupWindow` at the top of `main.py`. I missed this. Thank you very much for pointing that out. I will adjust as appropriate. Edit your answer and i'll upvote. Thanks a lot

Comment: Thank you very much. Works a treat. Really greatful and thank you for your patience, its been a long day and head hurts. Should've spotted that. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of `popupWindow.py`, put the line

```
from main import mainWindow
```

Then you can just call, e.g., `mainWindow.clearListBox()`

EDIT after OP posted code sample:
`clearListBox` is an instance method and as such can only be called on an instance, not on the class itself. You first have to instantiate an object of type `mainWindow`.

Comment: I tried this, however clearListBox requires self, as it is contained within the mainWindow class, and references to the list which is contained in the class

Comment: I guess you need to post a minimal example to progress here. `self` only makes sense inside a class, so I do not quite understand what you mean.

Comment: It's clear that the OP is looking at a complex program, and they don't know enough python to understand it. Don't try to teach him/her python in the space of this answer.

Comment: @alexis i do understand python thank you very much. I've had a long and busy day and i have a project deadline of tomorrow and my program barely functions. I'm tired and looking for a quick solution so please do not judge before you know the facts

Comment: @admin, I didn't mean to bust on you, but I do want to discourage well-meaning people from wasting their time. If this is your own code, then I was wrong about that part. Anyway I've given you my constructive advice in my answer.

Comment: @alexis your advice isn't constructive if it doesn't apply and isn't necessary. And yes the code is mine! It's for an A level computing project, i'd be disqualified if it were anyone else's code. Im sorry but i take serious offence to the fact you come in and assume i'm a fraud, then you tell me i don't know a language i know very well, then tell me to go learn it again... You need to rethink the way you talk to people, and the way you collect information BEFORE you decide to make "constructive advice".

Comment: I definitely didn't think you're a fraud, and I do apologize if that's the impression you got-- there's nothing inappropriate (or unusual) about having to work with someone else's code. Anyway we don't need to debate your python knowledge. Good luck with it.

Comment: @niceguy I have an instance of `mainWindow` class in `main.py` called `mainWin`. How would i access this from `popupWindow` class then without creating another instance?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question and on your comment to @niceguy's answer, it's clear that the solution to your problem is to go read [the python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/): Very soon you'll learn about modules (including `import`) and classes (including `self`, and calling class methods).

**Edit:** If you already understand about classes and instances, then here's your problem spelled out: Your class name is `mainWindow`, your instance is `mainWin`. You should be calling your functions on `mainWin`, e.g. `mainWin.addScouts(1)`; not on `mainWindow`.